# Preventing a mouse click on an HTML element layered by another HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, p5.js

I am using p5.js library to implement some visuals, along with reactJS.

What I have implemented: When I click and drag my mouse on screen, the background(say canvas) changes color. This is implemented using p5.js

What I want: I have created a draggable HTML element. However, When i click and drag my new element, the canvas also responds to the click and changes color. I want my click to only affect the new layered element, not the canvas.

I have tried setting the new element to be at higher z-Index and canvas container to be at a lower one. However, this doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: One cannot answer anything without looking at your code. My guess is that you are looking for `mousedown` (or something) event on `window` or `document`. Looking for the event on your canvas should fox your problem i.e. (in plain JS) **change `window.addEventListener(...)`/`document.addEventListener(...)` to `myCanvas.addEventListener(...)`**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having a look at your code, my best guess is that you have to stop the propagation of the event. So in your `dragStart` event, you could do this:

```
onDragStart={ e => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  // your code
 }
```

From the [mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation):

> The stopPropagation() method of the Event interface prevents further propagation of the current event in the capturing and bubbling phases